# Process.Start capturing standard output characters

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics

I have a Windows Service that is going to process results from plink.exe (Putty/SSH thing).  I'm currently successfully capturing the standard output and sending commands via the standard input to the process.

My problem is, the `OutputDataReceived` event doesn't seem to get raised until I receive a line break from the console application process.  The process prompts for a password and there isn't a line break until after I input a password.

So my question is, is there a way to process the Standard Output character-by-character, instead of line-by-line from the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class?

Here is my code:

```
_processInfoTest = new ProcessStartInfo();
_processInfoTest.FileName = serviceSettings.PlinkExecutable;
_processInfoTest.Arguments = GetPlinkArguments(serviceSettings);
_processInfoTest.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
_processInfoTest.RedirectStandardError = true;
_processInfoTest.RedirectStandardInput = true;
_processInfoTest.UseShellExecute = false;
_processInfoTest.CreateNoWindow = true;

_processTest = new Process();
_processTest.StartInfo = _processInfoTest;
_processTest.OutputDataReceived += processTest_OutputDataReceived;
_processTest.ErrorDataReceived += processTest_OutputDataReceived;
_processTest.Start();

_processTest.BeginOutputReadLine();
_processTest.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

And the event handler that handles the incoming lines of text:

```
private static void processTest_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string line = e.Data;

    if (line != null)
    {
        WcfServerHelper.BroadcastRemoteCallback(x => x.PlinkTextOutput(line, DateTime.Now));

        if (line.Contains("If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the"))
        {
            _processTest.StandardInput.Write("y");
            _processTest.StandardInput.Write("\n");
            _processTest.StandardInput.Flush();
        }

        // This code never gets called because the event doesn't get raised until a line-break occurs
        if (line.Contains("'s password:"))
        {
            _processTest.StandardInput.Write("mypassword");
            _processTest.StandardInput.Write("\n");
            _processTest.StandardInput.Flush();
        }

        if (line.Contains("Access granted"))
        {
            if (!_processTest.HasExited)
                _processTest.Kill();

            WcfServerHelper.BroadcastRemoteCallback(x => x.TestConnectionCallback(PlinkStatus.Success));
        }
        else if (line.Contains("Access denied") || line.Contains("Password authentication failed"))
        {
            if (!_processTest.HasExited)
                _processTest.Kill();

            WcfServerHelper.BroadcastRemoteCallback(x => x.TestConnectionCallback(PlinkStatus.InvalidUserOrPass));
        }
        else if (line.Contains("Host does not exist"))
        {
            if (!_processTest.HasExited)
                _processTest.Kill();

            WcfServerHelper.BroadcastRemoteCallback(x => x.TestConnectionCallback(PlinkStatus.InvalidHostname));
        }
        else if (line.Contains("Connection timed out"))
        {
            if (!_processTest.HasExited)
                _processTest.Kill();

            WcfServerHelper.BroadcastRemoteCallback(x => x.TestConnectionCallback(PlinkStatus.TimedOut));
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for an answer forever, and right after asking the question here I found my solution.

Btw, thanks DarkSquirrel, you hit the nail on the head.

Here is my solution:

```
_processInfoTest = new ProcessStartInfo();
_processInfoTest.FileName = serviceSettings.PlinkExecutable;
_processInfoTest.Arguments = GetPlinkArguments(serviceSettings);
_processInfoTest.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
_processInfoTest.RedirectStandardError = true;
_processInfoTest.RedirectStandardInput = true;
_processInfoTest.UseShellExecute = false;
_processInfoTest.CreateNoWindow = true;

WcfServerHelper.BroadcastRemoteCallback(x => x.PlinkTextOutput(_processInfoTest.Arguments, DateTime.Now));

_processTest = new Process();
_processTest.StartInfo = _processInfoTest;
_processTest.Start();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ProcessOutputCharacters(_processTest.StandardError);
    });

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ProcessOutputCharacters(_processTest.StandardOutput);
    });
```

And my methods:

```
private static void ProcessOutputCharacters(StreamReader streamReader)
{
    int outputCharInt;
    char outputChar;
    string line = string.Empty;

    while (-1 != (outputCharInt = streamReader.Read()))
    {
        outputChar = (char)outputCharInt;
        if (outputChar == '\n' || outputChar == '\r')
        {
            if (line != string.Empty)
            {
                ProcessLine("Output: " + line);
            }

            line = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            line += outputChar;

            if (line.Contains("login as:"))
            {
                _processTest.StandardInput.Write("myusername");
                _processTest.StandardInput.Write("\n");
                _processTest.StandardInput.Flush();
            }

            if (line.Contains("'s password:"))
            {
                _processTest.StandardInput.Write("mypassword");
                _processTest.StandardInput.Write("\n");
                _processTest.StandardInput.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void ProcessLine(string line)
{
    if (line != null)
    {
        WcfServerHelper.BroadcastRemoteCallback(x => x.PlinkTextOutput(line, DateTime.Now));

        if (line.Contains("If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the"))
        {
            _processTest.StandardInput.Write("y");
            _processTest.StandardInput.Write("\n");
            _processTest.StandardInput.Flush();
        }

        if (line.Contains("Access granted"))
        {
            if (!_processTest.HasExited)
                _processTest.Kill();

            WcfServerHelper.BroadcastRemoteCallback(x => x.TestConnectionCallback(PlinkStatus.Success));
        }
        else if (line.Contains("Access denied") || line.Contains("Password authentication failed"))
        {
            if (!_processTest.HasExited)
                _processTest.Kill();

            WcfServerHelper.BroadcastRemoteCallback(x => x.TestConnectionCallback(PlinkStatus.InvalidUserOrPass));
        }
        else if (line.Contains("Host does not exist"))
        {
            if (!_processTest.HasExited)
                _processTest.Kill();

            WcfServerHelper.BroadcastRemoteCallback(x => x.TestConnectionCallback(PlinkStatus.InvalidHostname));
        }
        else if (line.Contains("Connection timed out"))
        {
            if (!_processTest.HasExited)
                _processTest.Kill();

            WcfServerHelper.BroadcastRemoteCallback(x => x.TestConnectionCallback(PlinkStatus.TimedOut));
        }
    }

}
```

My only problem now is when I send the username or password (through StandardInput), it's only sending the first 5 characters.  I'll do some research on the issue and post that as a separate question if I need to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the event you are using is line buffered ... you will have to implement your own reader that calls Read() / ReadAsync() on the streamreader to get every char ...